# Bug trying to preserve linebreak in curl request in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I have the following script that works perfectly:

```
payload='{"index":{}}'$'\n''{"name":"Samuel"}'
echo "$payload" > tmp.json
curl -X POST  "http://my.api.com/" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data-binary @./tmp.json
```

I get a success response from `my.api.com` and I confirmed the entry made it into the database.

I don't like that I am writing a `tmp.json` to disk. I prefer to send the `payload` variable as is directly to the curl statement.  So I tried something like this:

```
payload='{"index":{}}'$'\n''{"name":"Samuel"}'
curl -X POST  "http://my.api.com/" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data @- << echo "$payload"
```

But I get an error response from `my.api.com` saying there are line break issues and syntax issues.  What Can I do to avoid writing the `payload` variable to disk?

I've tried many other things like:

```
--data "$payload"
--data `$payload`
--data @<(echo "$payload")
...etc...
```

But none of these are working.

Comment: have you tried curl -X POST  "http://my.api.com/" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"index":{}}'$'\n''{"name":"Samuel"}' ?

Comment: @aleti I just tried your command and `my.api.com` is telling me there are syntax and carriage return errors

Comment: Don't describe the error message ("there are line break issues and syntax issues"), [edit] your question to **show** the exact error message(s). Also show what a working `curl` command would look like if you weren't using a variable for `payload` and just had the text in-place instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<` is for here documents:

```
curl ... <<EOF
$payload
EOF
```

You want either a process substitution

```
curl ... < <(echo "$payload")
```

or a here string

```
curl ... <<< "$payload"
```

But if you already have the payload in a parameter, you don't need `@-` anymore:

```
curl ... --data "$payload"
```

I'm not sure why that would be producing the error you claim.

Comment: Each of the top 3 were successful!  Specifically these worked:  `--data-binary @- <<EOF
$payload
EOF`, `--data-binary @- < <(echo "$payload")`, and `--data-binary @- <<< "$payload"` all worked.  The `--data "$payload"` failed with errors stating there are line break and syntax issues.